# Problema con c#

Tags: c#

Una juguetería tiene mucho éxito en dos de sus productos: payasos y muñecas. Suele hacer venta por correo y la empresa de logística les cobra por peso de cada paquete así que deben calcular el peso de los payasos y muñecas que saldrán en cada paquete a demanda. Cada payaso pesa 112 g y cada muñeca 75 g. Escribir un programa que lea el número de payasos y muñecas vendidos en el último pedido y calcule el peso total del paquete que será enviado.

ahora bien este ejercicio originalmente era hecho en python y el profesor nos pidio que lo trasladaramos a C#

a partir de eso idee el siguiente codigo :

```
        int x = 112;
        int y = 75;
        decimal ventaP;
        decimal ventaM;
        decimal totalPeso;

        Console.WriteLine("cuantos payasos vendiste :");
        ventaP = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("cuantas muñecas vendiste:");
        ventaM = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        totalPeso = (x * ventaP + y * ventaM);
        
        Console.WriteLine("el peso total es ", totalPeso);
```

El problema recae que al probar el programa solicita bien los datos de venta , pero al momento de revelar el totalpeso este se queda en blanco.

Comment: Me queda la pregunta de porqué el número de unidades de payasos y muñecas es de tipo decimal. Piensas mandar un tercio, o media muñeca, y tres cuartos de payaso en una caja para poder cumplir con un peso máximo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar:

```
Console.WriteLine("el peso total es {0}", totalPeso);
```

---

Funciona como una *plantilla* en la que toma *n* elementos a sustituir, por ejemplo quisiéramos mostrar más elementos podríamos usar:

```
string nombre = "Foo";
string apodo = "Bar";
decimal edad = 2;
Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}, apodo: {1}, edad: {2}",nombre, apodo, edad);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias master , me funciono!

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] para ver como marcar como correcta una respuesta. Además, no está de más recordar que aparte de la substitución de elementos, simplemente puedes concatenar el string: `Console.WriteLine("El peso es " + totalPeso);`